# Failed to open file in Verilog on EDA Playground site

Tags: verilog

I tried to open a file `ff.txt` and write into it some random numbers, say seven times. I used EDA playground website for it:

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/TCC

When I try to run, I get this error:

```
# ** Warning: (vsim-3533) [FOFIW] - Failed to open file "ff.txt" for writing.
# Permission denied. (errno = EACCES) : design.sv(6)
```

Why don't I have access to the `ff.txt` file?

```
     module fopenclose();
       integer mcd,number;
       initial begin
         mcd=$fopen("ff.txt");
         repeat(7) begin
           number=$random;
           $fdisplay(mcd,"Number is",number);
         end
         $fclose(mcd);
       end
       initial #2 $display("%d",mcd);
     endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDA playground most likely does not provide filesystem access.  You will probably need to run this in a simulator on your local computer.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been **fixed** in EDA Playground, and the code now works correctly.

The issue was that the *ff.txt* file was read-only.